# Style Jquery Nested Accordions Different from Parent

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I have a standard nested JQuery UI Accordion.  My issue is that I want to style the inner accordions differently from the parent accordion. I know what CSS rules apply styles to the accordion but I cannot find a selector that will target the inner accordion.

The only selector that even came close was the :nth-child() pseudo selector. The problem is that I don't know how many elements the inner accordion will have nor how many elements the top accordion will have.

The one rule is that I know there will never be a third level of nesting.

This CSS rule sets the style for all the accordion headers

```
.ui-accordion-header.ui-state-default {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #19A053;
    border-color: #19A053;
}
```

I need a way to do something like this now

```
.ui-accordion-header.ui-state-default if-inside-another-accordion{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #dddddd;
    border-color: #dddddd;
}
```

In case you are an expert in CSS selectors but have never seen the JQuery generated HTML, here is a sample of a nested accordions generated code.

```
<div id="content">
  <div role="tablist" style="display: block;" class="gw_accordion ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset">
    <div tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="ui-accordion-1-panel-0" id="ui-accordion-1-header-0" role="tab" class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><a class="gw_chapter_menu_link" href="#24" alt="">Top Level Header 1</a></div>
    <div aria-hidden="false" aria-expanded="true" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ui-accordion-1-header-0" id="ui-accordion-1-panel-0" style="display: block;" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active">
      <p>some text here</p>
      <div role="tablist" style="display: block;" class="gw_accordion ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset">
        <div tabindex="0" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="ui-accordion-2-panel-0" id="ui-accordion-2-header-0" role="tab" class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span><a class="gw_chapter_menu_link" href="#27" alt="Maybe Now???">Nested Header 1</a></div>
        <div aria-hidden="true" aria-expanded="false" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ui-accordion-2-header-0" id="ui-accordion-2-panel-0" style="display: none;" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
          <p>some text here</p>
        </div>
        <div tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="ui-accordion-2-panel-1" id="ui-accordion-2-header-1" role="tab" class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span><a class="gw_chapter_menu_link" href="#25" alt="">Nested Header 2</a></div>
        <div aria-hidden="true" aria-expanded="false" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ui-accordion-2-header-1" id="ui-accordion-2-panel-1" style="display: none;" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
         <p>some text here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="ui-accordion-1-panel-1" id="ui-accordion-1-header-1" role="tab" class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span><a class="gw_chapter_menu_link" href="#26" alt="I hope this works">Top Level Header 2</a></div>
    <div aria-hidden="true" aria-expanded="false" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ui-accordion-1-header-1" id="ui-accordion-1-panel-1" style="display: none;" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
      <p>some text here</p>
      <div role="tablist" style="display: block;" class="gw_accordion ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset">
        <div tabindex="0" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="ui-accordion-3-panel-0" id="ui-accordion-3-header-0" role="tab" class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span><a class="gw_chapter_menu_link" href="#28" alt="Really">Nested Header 1(for second top header)</a></div>
        <div aria-hidden="true" aria-expanded="false" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ui-accordion-3-header-0" id="ui-accordion-3-panel-0" style="display: none;" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
          <p>some text here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it just looks like you need to do this:

```
.ui-accordion.ui-state-default .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header.ui-state-default {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #dddddd;
    border-color: #dddddd;
}
```

OR, depending on your reliance on whether it's in the .ui-state-default state, you could also simplify it to:

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #dddddd;
    border-color: #dddddd;
}
```

That's basically saying "Only apply these styles to a .ui-accordian-header if it's the descendant of a .ui-accordion that's also a descendant of a .ui-accordion element."

Another simple way to visualize this might be like this:

Here's a container with a header, within another container with a header:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="header">Header 1</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="header">Header 2</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

To style just **Header 2** I would do this:

```
.container .container .header {
    styles here will only apply to header 2, not header 1
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I did try the descendant selector method but I didn't leave a space between them. Sort of important!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah. I can see how you might do that with all those long class names. Easy to miss. Glad you got it sorted out!